# Is it possible to allocate array inside function and return it using reference?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, allocation

I've tried using a tripple pointer, but it keeps failing. Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int set(int *** list) {
  int count, i;
  printf("Enter number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &count);
  (*list) = (int **) malloc ( sizeof (int) * count);

  for ( i = 0; i<count;i++ ) {
    (**list)[count] = 123;
  }
  return count;
}

int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  int ** list;
  int count;

  count = set(&list);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: I made myself a rule long ago that if my code has `***` anywhere I have to rewrite it.

Comment: I've heard of this rule, but in this case, *** will save creating a function that would be called only once.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean recoding, it means redesigning your data structures so that you don't need all those layers of indirection.

Comment: yOu should use `(**list)[i]=123` instead of `(**list)[count]=123`

Comment: @Grant :writing [count] at index is that correct ? what do you exactly want

Comment: @Grant are you trying to make a multi-dimension array or what??

Comment: Obligatory "three star programmer" joke: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YxUlDo9IaLEJ:c2.com/cgi/wiki%3FThreeStarProgrammer+&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to allocate inside function since you might forget and not free it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you call list is actually an array. You might do it the following way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

ssize_t set(int ** ppList) 
{
  ssize_t count = -1;

  printf("Enter number:\n");
  scanf("%zd", &count);

  if (0 <= count)
  {
    (*ppList) = malloc(count * sizeof **ppList);

    if (*ppList)
    {
      size_t i = 0;
      for (; i < count; ++i)
      {
        (*ppList)[i] = 42;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      count = -1;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

int main (void)
{
  int * pList = NULL;
  size_t count = 0;

  {
    ssize_t result = set(&pList);

    if (0 > result)
    {
      perror("set() failed");
    }
    else
    {
      count = result;
    }
  }

  if (count)
  {
    /* use pList */
  }

  ...

  free(pList);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand your question you want to return an array which is allocated in another function : here is the simple version of this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int* set(int *list) {
  int count, i;
  printf("Enter number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &count);
  list = (int *) malloc ( sizeof (int) * count);

  for ( i = 0; i<count;i++ ) {
    list[i] = 123;
  }

  return list;
}

int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  int *list;
  list = set(list);
  //Use whatever you want to do with that array 
  free(list); // don't forget to free
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not checked if malloc fails condition

Answer (score 1):

you have an array of integer arrays. Let's look at your set function closely:

```
for (i = 0; i < count;i++ ) {
    (**list)[count] = 123;
}
```

As you can see you are treating every array object like an integer value.
That should be a nested loop:

```
for (i to n)
    // allocate each array
    for (k to m)
        // assign value for each value of array
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. But the question is: How to allocade 1-dimensional array and return it using reference?

Comment: @Grant by reference do you mean `return &array` or what?

Comment: By using reference I mean as an output parameter.

Comment: @Grant

for (i to n)<br/>
    (**list)[i] = new int[desired_length_of_each_array]<br/>
    for (k to m)<br/>
        (*list)[k] = desired_value<br/>

But i assume you are doing this to learn the c syntax. Because it's not a good programming style to use a tripple pointer, since the syntax is very confusing.

of the topic: By the way i am new to this forum and i would like to learn how to enter a new line in a comment.