# How do I fill an array with pointers to structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have to fill an array with pointers to structs.
The struct is:

```
typedef struct {
  char* name;
  double weiten[3];
} springer;
```

Now I want to fill an array springer *spr[] . I have an array of strings called namen and n is the number of elements that I want to have in the array in the end.

The function to fill the array:

```
void fuellen(springer *spr[], const char* namen[], int n){
spr=calloc(n,sizeof(springer));
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    (*spr[i]).name=calloc(30,sizeof(char));
     strcpy((*spr[i]).name, namen[i]);
    spr[i]->weiten[0]=zufallsWeite();
    spr[i]->weiten[1]=zufallsWeite();
    spr[i]->weiten[2]=zufallsWeite();
}
}
```

So the structs that the array points to should be filled with structs that have the names in my char-array as names. The array that is also part of the structs should be filled with 3 randomly generated numers between 6 and 9 (zufallsWeite() gives you those.

Now in the main function I want to use the function:

```
const int N = 5;
const char *names[] = {"Tom Mueller","Timo Meier","Ulf Sommer","Tobi 
Winter","Uwe Schmidt"};

springer *spr[N];
fuellen(spr, names, N);
```

The build works but then the program shuts down and I get an error message.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I have been looking for a while but I have not found anything.

Comment: If you want static declaration of array right way to do it is:     springer spr[array_size];

Comment: *"I get an error message"* - would be helpful if you included what the error message states.

Comment: using `A->B` instead of `(*A).B` is more readable

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208829/1971013) help? Did you step through with a debugger?

Comment: `springer *spr[]` is not an array of objects, it is an array of pointers. Probably you just want an array of objects: `springer spr[]`.

Comment: you are using `calloc` witch set all bit from allocated data to 0 then you `strcpy` to set the data to its real value. sound like you could have use `malloc`

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: If your namen array is really constant, you can simply make objects' names point to its elements, without any allocations and copies.

Comment: @bipll, if you do that, then the name fields in the springer declaration must also be const.

Comment: Instead of allocating memory and then copying a string into it, use `strdup()`! Technically it's not part of the C standard, but virtually all standard libraries support it.

Comment: @jwdonahue Chances are, the really should be.

Comment: @bipll, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You have (comments added by me):

```
void fuellen(springer *spr[], const char* namen[], int n){
    // At this point, spr is a pointer to the first element in
    // the array that was passed into the funtion.
    spr=calloc(n,sizeof(springer));
    // Now spr, a local pointer value, points to zeroed memory in the heap.
    // The following loop copies strings from namen[] to spr[].
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        //(*spr[i]).name=calloc(30,sizeof(char));
        //strcpy((*spr[i]).name, namen[i]);
        strdup(namen[i];)
        spr[i]->weiten[0]=zufallsWeite();
        spr[i]->weiten[1]=zufallsWeite();
        spr[i]->weiten[2]=zufallsWeite();
    }
    // Unfortunately, all that work, including the heap
    // allocation is lost when this function returns.
}
```

Just don't overwrite `spr` with a call to `calloc`.

```
void fuellen(springer *spr[], const char* namen[], int n){
    // spr[] was allocated by the caller!
    // Allocate each element of the array and initialize the struct.
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        spr[i] = malloc(sizeof(springer));
        spr[i]->name = strdup(namen[i]);
        spr[i]->weiten[0]=zufallsWeite();
        spr[i]->weiten[1]=zufallsWeite();
        spr[i]->weiten[2]=zufallsWeite();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why your code fails and the shortest fix. I would head bipal's advice above, and make the name field of the springer struct a const pointer, then you don't have to deal with all those extra allocations/deallocations for copies of string constants.